# Pandas GroupBy for Highest Counted String?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Given a DataFrame like this:

[image: BeginningDataframe]

Desired outcome:

[image: DesiredOutput]

There are solutions that are close to what I'm looking for using `groupby` and `count`, but I'm not sure how to get it right. Basically, I want the recommendation that has the highest count for each symbol to be returned. So I assume pseudo code might look something like:

```
new_df = df.groupby(['Symbol'])['Recommendation'].count().max()
```

...but of course this is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could apply `mode`:

```
new_df = df.groupby('Symbol')['Recommendation'].apply(lambda x: x.mode())
```

I guess we could also do the following:

```
s = df.groupby(['Symbol','Recommendation']).size()
s = s.groupby(level=0).transform('max').eq(s)
out = s.index[s].to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)
```